# Set Text in NSTextView with NSData

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdata, nstextview

I have an instance of NSData that I stored from a previous run of my application. I want to set an NSTextView's text using this data. It is RTF and I can't figure out how to do this. Any ideas or suggestions? It needs to be done with code and not Interface Builder.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
//First convert a NSData object to a NSString object.

NSData *aData;
//assign aData to what you want it to.
NSAttributedString *aStr;
aStr = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:aData documentAttributes:NULL] autorelease];
//then set the textView to that value.

[[yourTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:aStr];
```

Comment: I assume he wants to interpret the RTF, not just display it.

Comment: thanks for the response, but when I try to set the textview's attributed string I get this error


*** -[NSBigMutableString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSData *myData; // RTF data
NSAttributedString *myString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTFD:myData documentAttributes:NULL];

[[yourTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:myString];
```

thyrgle is close, but NSAttributedString needs to be initialized using

```
initWithRTFD: documentAttributes:
```

instead of

```
initWithRTF: documentAttributes:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an NSAttributedString using RTF data, and the NSTextStorage owned by the NSTextView derives from NSMutableAttributedString.  I think you can put the pieces together from that.

Answer (score 0):

check that are you implemented any category on textfield or uiview?(any in built ui on which you implemented category) if yes then remove that category and check it again.